# Int array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to loop through the array and get the elements inside in C++. Here is my code:

```
int result;
int index_array [] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

for (int count =0; count < index_array.length() ; count++){
  if(count%2 == 0){
    cout << "Elements at the even index are " << index_array[count] << endl;
  }
}
```

If I change the `for` loop to:

```
for (int count =0; count < 10 ; count++){
```

There is no error because my array only consists of 10 items. But if I used the `.length()` method, there is an error which is *expression must have a class type*. I have no idea what is it, as in if it is in Eclipse, there contains a more detailed error description. What might be wrong?

### Updated answer

```
    for (int count =0; count < sizeof(index_array)/sizeof(index_array [0]) ; count++){
    if((count+1)%2 == 0){
        cout << "Elements at the even index are " << index_array[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not "Objects" per say in C++, and have therefore no associated method. The error "expression must have class type" expresses just that : you can only call methods on classes (or structures).

Comment: If you're sure you want a fixed length array, you can change `index_array.length()` to `sizeof( index_array ) / sizeof( index_array[0] )`

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean? Can you give me some example?

Comment: @Rauryn: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: @Rauryn you've come from a language where everything is an object. In the lower-level languages like C++, that's not true. The array is just a space in memory. It doesn't have any methods, or even know how big it is. The compiler does (because in this case it's fixed-length), so `sizeof` can tell you.

Comment: Oh okay okay. I thought C++ was kind of similar with java. So no matter is vector or array, they only can use sizeof method?

Comment: `sizeof` is not a method. its an operator implemented by each implementation. you can think of primitve types as a bunch of memory locations given a special name.

Comment: Err, not everything is an object, even in Java. Specifically, it has `int`, `double` and so on. Python, on the other hand, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call `length()` on `int index_array[]`, it is a primitive array, not an object.

You could call `size()`, if you have, for example `vector<int> index_array`.

Comment: So only vector works with .length method? And array can only use the sizeof method?

Comment: [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) has `size()` method which does what you want. Yes, primitive arrays have no methods. All you can do is call sizeof *operator* on them.

Answer (score 2):

There is not `.length` for a plain array in C++.
Instead use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and you can use method [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) :

```
std::vector<int> index_array {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

for (int count =0; count < index_array.size() ; count++){
    if(count%2 == 0){
        cout << "Elements at the even index are " << index_array[count] << endl;
    }
}
```

Also in your case, you can calculate the length of the array:

```
int length = sizeof(index_array)/sizeof(index_array[0]);
```

Comment: I wrote the vector like this : vector<int> index_array {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}; But there's an error at the first curly braces there. What's wrong?

Comment: Ah, I wrote the code in `-std=c++11` mode. you can change the compiler mode to C++11 to have initializer lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index_array [] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

This is not an object that you can invoke some `length()` method on. Instead, it's a regular array, just like in C.

You can do one of two things.

The first is to use one of the C++ collection classes such as `std::vector` (adjustable size) or `std::array` (constant size) with their `size()` methods:

```
// C++11 syntax
std::vector<int> index_array {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

// Pre C++11 syntax
int ia_src[] = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
vector<int> index_array (ia_src, ia_src + sizeof (ia_src) / sizeof (*ia_src));

std::array<int,10> index_array = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
```

The second is to simply treat the array as an array, in which case the length of that array can be found with the expression:

```
sizeof (index_array) / sizeof (*index_array)
```

Just be aware that this only works for arrays. If you pass that array to a function, it will decay to a pointer to the first element and `sizeof` will no longer work as you expect. You need to get the size while it's still an array and pass that along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in c++ are not object (classes) so they don't have neither methods nor attributes.
May be you can use the Array class instead and get the size like `std::array::size()`

Comment: C++ is a case-sensitivity language. Not `Array`, but `array`.